# Проблемы с Travis CI. Java-проект

Tags: java, maven, travis

Впервые с ним работаю. Maven-проект. Крашит. Сам .travis.yml файл лежит в корне проекта и заполнен таким образом:

```
language: java
install: mvn install
mvn test -B
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

Ошибка:

```
The command "eval mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

Их таких несколько, но суть одна и та же. Без *install: mvn install* то же самое. Это уже попытки фикса, которые выудил из тырнета.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?